# How to initialize nested structures in C++

Tags: c++, nested, structure

i was trying to perform stack functions using nested structures.
But i am facing problem initializing the stack.

its the problem with the initialize function of LinkList structure in the code given below.

Please help and let me know what can i do to run this code completely.

thanks in advance

CODE:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class stack{
    struct ch;
    ch * ptr;

    public:
        void initialize();
        void push(int *);
        int* pop();
        int* peek();
};


struct stack::ch{
    struct LinkList{
        int * data;
        LinkList * next;
        void initialize(int* dat, ch* nxt);
    }*head;
};

/*this is where i am facing problem*/
void stack::ch::LinkList::initialize(int *dat, ch *nxt){
        data = dat;
        if(nxt->head)   //as i cannot access head of nxt,so code is crashing 
        next = nxt->head;
        else
            next = 0;
    }

    void stack::initialize()
    {
        ptr = 0;

    }

    void stack::push(int *dat)
    {
        ch::LinkList* newNode = new ch::LinkList;
        newNode->initialize(dat,ptr);
        ptr->head = newNode;    
    }

    int* stack::pop()
    {
        if(ptr == 0)
            return 0;
        ch::LinkList* oldHead = ptr->head;
        ptr->head = ptr->head->next;
        int * dat = oldHead->data;
        delete oldHead;
        return dat;
    }

    int* stack::peek()
    {
        if(ptr->head == 0)
            return 0;
        return ptr->head->data;
    }

    int main()
    {
        stack obj;
        obj.initialize();
        int a = 10;
        int b  = 11;
        int c  = 12;
        int d  = 13;
        obj.push(&a);
        obj.push(&b);
        obj.push(&c);
        obj.push(&d);

        int *f;
        while((f = obj.pop())!=0)
        {
            cout<<*(obj.peek())<<endl;
            //obj.pop();
        }           

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you debug it ? You should get a compiler diagnostic on what is going wrong ? That should be the easiest way to figure what is going wrong.

Comment: "I am facing problem" doesn't do much to tell us what that problem _is_, does it?

Comment: yeah i now that ptr is null and that is making if(nxt->head) not accessible and the code is crashing..

Comment: The thing is i am not able to figure out how should i initialize data and next,,without crashing,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should debug your code by yourself.**

```
void stack::push(int *dat)
{
    ch::LinkList* newNode = new ch::LinkList;
    newNode->initialize(dat,ptr);
    ptr->head = newNode;    
}

void stack::ch::LinkList::initialize(int *dat, ch *nxt){
    data = dat;
    if(nxt->head)    
        next = nxt->head;
    else
        next = 0;
}
```

Note that: `ptr` is `nullptr`,so `nxt` is a `nullptr` too.
So you crash...
make `ptr` not null, and fix your pop function bugs, that will ok.

Comment: "You should debug your code by yourself" immediately followed by you instead debugging it for him...

Comment: i debugged it, but what to do in this case,,that is what i am not able to figure out,,i dont want to change the layout of the code,,but want to do something that will allow me to access ptr->head.

Comment: i tried this: void stack::push(int *dat)
 {
  ch::LinkList* newNode = new ch::LinkList;
  newNode->initialize(dat,ptr);
  if(ptr)
  ptr->head = newNode;
  else 
   ptr = newNode;
 }

Comment: this is making me pass through initialize but then i get struck in push() again,,in making ptr->head = newNode;

Comment: @RavenderSinghDahiya - replace ptr=0 with ptr = new ch in stack::initialize() you program can run more ,but in your stack::pop() always has a bug. Good Luck.

Comment: @Ron Tang:: thanks for the help...its done,,that was the only problem,,i was trying to access ptr->head without allocating memory for ptr....

Comment: Also i debugged my pop() code..its running good now,,i was able to run it all well and completely...thanks for ur help again..:-)

Comment: @RavenderSinghDahiya  - Do you still have any other problem ? You can close this issue and accept this answer.Thanks.